# Output resistance of CE amplifier small signal model

Tags: bjt, resistance, output, common-emitter

I was studying input/output impedance of CE amplifier small signal model and I wanted to know why the output impedance (looking from the collector) is just Rc in parallel with dynamic output resistance of the transistor (ro).
[image]

When calculating output impedance why are RB and rbe neglected? and also is the current through Rc just Ic if so why ?

Comment: An ideal current source has infinite resistance. So for impedance "looking in" you can just throw it away. At that point it's pretty obvious that \$r_o\$ is in parallel with \$R_\text{C}\$ and nothing else is there anymore to worry about. So what else would the impedance look like?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmHpXZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using Mathematica, I wrote the following code:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ix == I1 + I2, I1 == Ix + I0, I2 == Iy + I6, 
   0 == Iy + I0 + I5, I6 == I3 + I4, I5 == I3 + I4, I1 == (Vx)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vx - V1)/R2, I3 == (V1)/R3, I4 == (V1)/R4}, {Ix, I0, I1, I2,
    I3, I4, I5, I6, V1}]]

Out[1]={{Ix -> (Iy R1 R3 R4 + (R1 + R2) R3 Vx + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 Vx)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  I0 -> -((Iy R3 R4 + (R3 + R4) Vx)/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))), 
  I1 -> Vx/R1, I2 -> (Iy R3 R4 + (R3 + R4) Vx)/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)),
   I3 -> (R4 (-Iy R2 + Vx))/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I4 -> (R3 (-Iy R2 + Vx))/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)), 
  I5 -> -(((R3 + R4) (Iy R2 - Vx))/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))), 
  I6 -> -(((R3 + R4) (Iy R2 - Vx))/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))), 
  V1 -> (R3 R4 (-Iy R2 + Vx))/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *When calculating output impedance why are RB and rbe neglected?*

Because the lower end of the current source and rE are grounded. End of story.

The current through Rc is modified / dependent on external load currents.